# Pokemon go unable to get game data from server

Tags: pokemon-go

I tried to open game in my device and get this message "not able to get data from the server" even i didn't played from last 2 days

Comment: Did you used any third party tools? GPS spoofing or any tricky stuff on your account?

Answer (score 1):

I think you are permanbanned for botting reasons or obvious GPS spoofing with the recent banwaves Niantic has been giving out.